# how to seprate alphanumeric string into number and alphabets

Tags: java, android, string, textview

For example string is `JD85DS8796`

There are 4 text views and I want to set each text view like:

In 1st text-view `JD`, in 2nd text-view `85`, in 3rd text-view `DS`, in 4th text-view `8796`.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: I don't think there is any built in method for that..you might have to write an algorithm for that..what have you tried so far?

Comment: IS THIS YOUR DYNAMIC/STATIC STRING?

Comment: I am developing android app in that user enter the vehicle number (ex car no: GA 14 DN 5437 ) in edit view, but when user enter that number is without space. i want to split that no as in example. Then set it to Different textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way, this will gives you digits value, then remaining string can be separated as string

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher("JD85DS8796");
m.find();
String inputInt = m.group();
textview.setText(inputInt);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, yes there is a crazy regex you can give to String.split:

```
"[^A-Z0-9]+|(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=[A-Z])"
```

What this means is to split on any sequence of characters which aren't digits or capital letters as well as between any occurrence of a capital letter followed by a digit or any digit followed by a capital letter. The trick here is to match the space between a capital letter and a digit (or vice-versa) without consuming the letter or the digit. For this we use look-behind to match the part before the split and look-ahead to match the part after the split.

However as you've probably noticed, the above regex is quite a bit more complicated than your VALID_PATTERN. This is because what you're really doing is trying to extract certain parts from the string, not to split it.

So finding all the parts of the string which match the pattern and putting them in a list is the more natural approach to the problem. This is what your code does, but it does so in a needlessly complicated way. You can greatly simplify your code, by simply using Pattern.matcher like this:

```
private static final Pattern VALID_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+|[A-Z]+");

private List<String> parse(String toParse) {
List<String> chunks = new LinkedList<String>();
Matcher matcher = VALID_PATTERN.matcher(toParse);
while (matcher.find()) {
    chunks.add( matcher.group() );
    }
return chunks;
}
```

If you do something like this more than once, you might want to refactor the body of this method into a method findAll which takes the string and the pattern as arguments, and then call it as findAll(toParse, VALID_PATTERN) in parse.